# Bluetooth 3.0 inquiry timing

Tags: bluetooth

I'm working with fast Bluetooth detection and inquiry. I know a few seconds are needed to accomplish BD_ADDR and name detection while using Bluetooth 2.0 devices.
Does anybody know whether anything faster, or any kind of fast pairing or name beaconing ares expected with Bluetooth 3.0?

I found out the improvements are more on the transmission rate, once the link is established, but nothing on the inquiry / exhange of information without pairing side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major improvement to Inquiry (device discovery) was at v2.1 with EIR (Extended Inquiry Response).  Previously only the Device Address (and CoD, IIRC) was sent in the Inquiry Response.  The discoverer then had to make a ACL connection to read the remote's Device Name -- and then query its SDP database etc etc.  The Extended Inquiry Response can include the Device Name along with other things -- supported Class Ids etc.

See section 7.7.38 Extended Inquiry Result Event in the HCI chapter (Vol 2, Part E), in spec v2.1 (the one I have at hand just now).

e.g.
http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Nokia_Symbian3_Developers_Library/GUID-F2A793F1-A5B5-526B-B147-771D440B13A2.html

Comment: Just a minor edit on ananjmcf's comment, L2cap connection was not required, but a Bluetooth ACL connection was required previously to read the name. With BT2.1+ devices that do EIR this info can be part of the inquiry response (this is optional stuff and not necessarily required by all devices to include this info in inquiry response)